# How to sign PDFs from a C# web application using logged user certificate?

Tags: c#, web, certificate, signing

I should implement a `.NET` web application using `windows authentication` through which the users can sign server-stored PDFs using **the user's certificate** (The certificate should be taken from user machine). I tried two solutions:

1. Setting `SSL Certificate` as Required in `IIS`, the server receives only the certificate's public key, while the private key is required to sign the PDFs.
2. with a `silverlight` control the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` cannot be used, specifically I can't call the method `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection`, which allows the users to select a certificate from their machine.

Also I mention that I tried to take the user's certificates using javascript, but it seems that javascript doesn't offer features for this purpose.

What can I do to reach my goal (with above approaches or another one)?